# Need a help with creation of test class for trigger

Tags: trigger, code-coverage

I do not why but my precedent question was closed. So i post new question. I need your help to write the test class for the code below. I tried millions of time but nothing works, i reached the limit of my beginner knowledge in triggers.
here is my triger:
trigger UpdateLeadLastMQLDate on Event (before update) {

Map<Id, Lead> leads = new Map<Id, Lead>();

```
for(Event record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.WhoId?.getSObjectType() == Lead.sObjectType) {
        leads.put(record.WhoId, null);
    }
}
leads.putAll([SELECT Last_MQL_Date_Time__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leads.keySet()]);
for(Event record: Trigger.new) {
    record.Lead_Last_MQL_Date_Time__c= leads.get(record.WhoId)?.Last_MQL_Date_Time__c;
}
```

}

Here the test class:
@isTest (seeAllData=false)
private class TestUpdateLeadLastMQLDate {
static testMethod void testEventTrigger() {
// set up leads
List testLeads = new List();
Lead lead1 = new Lead();
lead1.Company = 'Test 1 New Company';
lead1.LastName = 'Aigul';
lead1.LeadSource = 'LeadIQ';
lead1.Status = 'SQL';
lead1.Email = 'test@test.com';
lead1.Country = 'France';
lead1.Last_MQL_Date_Time__c = DateTime.parse('17/06/2020 13:00');
//lead1.Business_Type__c = 'App/Business';
//lead1.Lead_Role__c = 'Product';
testLeads.add(lead1);

```
    Lead lead2 = new Lead();
    lead2.Company = 'Test 12';
    lead2.LastName = 'Jordan';
    lead2.LeadSource = 'LeadIQ';
    lead2.Status = 'SQL';
    lead2.Email = 'test23@test.com';
    lead2.Country = 'France';
    lead2.Last_MQL_Date_Time__c = DateTime.parse('17/06/2020 13:00');
    //lead2.Business_Type__c = 'App/Business';
    //lead2.Lead_Role__c = 'Product';
    testLeads.add(lead2);
    insert testLeads;
    
    // set up Events
    List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
    Event event1 = new Event();
    event1.WhoId=testLeads[0].Id; 
    event1.Subject= 'Test0';
    event1.Type='Autre';
    event1.STARTDATETIME=System.today();
    event1.ENDDATETIME=System.today();
    event1.Sales_Rep__c = '0052o000009lZyVAAU';
    event1.Description = 'bla';
    events.add(event1);
    
    
    Event event2 = new Event();
    event2.WhoId=testLeads[1].Id; 
    event2.Subject= 'Test1';
    event2.Type='Autre';
    event2.STARTDATETIME=System.today();
    event2.ENDDATETIME=System.today();
    event2.Sales_Rep__c = '0052o000009lZyVAAU';
    event2.Description = 'bla';
    events.add(event2);

    Test.startTest();
    insert events;
    Test.stopTest();
    
    /*List<Lead> leadResults = [SELECT Last_MQL_Date_Time__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :testLeads];*/
    List<Event> eventResults = [SELECT Lead_Last_MQL_Date_Time__c FROM Event WHERE Id IN :events];
    for (Event e : eventResults) {
        //System.assertEquals(true, l.SQL_Scheduled__c);
        System.assertEquals(e.Lead_Last_MQL_Date_Time__c, DateTime.parse('17/06/2020 13:00'));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. Simply fixing your original question is sufficient to get an answer.

Comment: I know but my first post was closed... i do not know who closed it. So now it is opened and i do not not why. ANyway sure will not post duplicates

Comment: It was originally closed with a [tag:canonical-qa] duplicate question, designed to help people who don't have enough experience writing tests (we are not here to *write* tests, but we'll certainly help *fix* them). I reopened your question after you included the test code. This is how the process works here. You'll get used to it.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for info. I wondered why it was closed :-))